# bash: bin/v2: No such file or directory when deploying Go/Gin app to Koyeb

Tags: go, deployment, go-gin, htmx

I recently started learning Go and I decided to build out a portfolio project to get more experience with the language. The app builds and runs with no error locally, but when I try to deploy it... (anywhere) but lets day Koyeb, I am getting the following errors.

```
Instance is starting
Instance is unhealthy
bash: bin/v2: No such file or directory
Instance is unhealthy
bash: bin/v2: No such file or directory
Instance is unhealthy
Instance terminated in nomad
```

I have no idea what the bin/v2 is about. My module does have "...2023.com/v2" in the title, but I figured that was just a coincidence. I realize this post is really vague, but I don't really know what else share. None of my code makes any reference to bin/v2. I'll leave the repo link here, since I have no idea of what I'm looking for that might be the problem.

https://github.com/guitarkeegan/guitarkeegan-2023